# How come the user has less reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki, reputation-history, reputation-audit

I went through a profile of Jeff who had asked a famed question as seen in [Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

having 1326 upvotes .
By my calculation , this one question can only shot his reputation points above 10k .

Still he has a low reputation of 1,783 . Why ?

Comment: Probably because his post because [a Community Wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) back in 2009. "**Post Made Community Wiki** by question having more than 30 answers " [according to the edit revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions?page=2).

Comment: why down votes :P ... it seems a logical question

Comment: @Yatin lack of research effort I guess. Going to the help center and looking up what a community wiki post is isn't a daunting task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The** biggest factor was that his question [went to Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions?page=2) *very* quickly after it was posted.

This is the only window of time he would have had to gain *any* rep from that question:

[image]

Since Community Wiki content [does not impact reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/175248), he wouldn't have gained any more reputation after the system automatically converted it.

Comment: Whats the link going into Community wiki has on rep ??

Comment: When a post becomes a community wiki, you don't receive any reputation from it anymore (only badges).